# How to center bootstrap grid if it will not total 12 column but 9 column with one row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center 3 column, it will take total 9 column bootstrap but not 12 column so, I need to center this type of bootstrap 4 column.
please see the snippet what I am wrong. I am trying to use justify-content-center but it's not totally center in mobile device if I use

`justify-content-center`

in sm device, the last child don't want to center but in left side.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
    .border{
       border:  1px solid red!important;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="p-0 m-0">

   <div class="container">
       <div class="row justify-content-sm-start justify-content-md-center">
           <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3  border">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum dolores, veritatis tempore nihil explicabo mollitia doloribus laborum! Cupiditate, saepe. Commodi, mollitia? Sit quia magnam commodi inventore impedit quam nam voluptate est odio, alias unde a doloribus aliquid beatae eaque recusandae corrupti delectus reprehenderit ipsa dolorum hic. Labore possimus eos amet. Officia porro vel, veritatis minus natus tempore ratione quo nostrum, adipisci laboriosam temporibus qui. Architecto possimus laboriosam explicabo iusto! Minus iusto amet aperiam voluptatum libero placeat vero, molestias dolorem vitae eius doloremque optio? Ea blanditiis distinctio similique labore odio culpa, quis nobis veniam sapiente sed. Illum labore saepe doloremque sapiente.</div>
           <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 border ">Et laborum libero dignissimos ea molestias, quae rerum veritatis harum quidem soluta! Perferendis cumque minima modi enim ducimus exercitationem accusantium facilis dolore corrupti ab, esse autem. Illo inventore tenetur aut recusandae nostrum dolorum dolore doloribus nihil cupiditate. Voluptas ex commodi expedita atque sint obcaecati iure explicabo ipsam quo consequatur laudantium officia autem recusandae sapiente quae excepturi a culpa sunt, ratione quis tenetur vitae odio corrupti. Perspiciatis blanditiis, debitis eaque sequi porro hic minus ex adipisci iste ad accusamus aut atque eius mollitia error ducimus labore praesentium sed dolorem? Incidunt eaque ex eum unde ducimus et libero repudiandae aliquid porro nesciunt.</div>
           <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3  border">Laboriosam itaque labore iusto quidem ipsum quae et ipsam alias incidunt cumque, nobis quaerat corporis inventore! Quibusdam et ipsam quam pariatur unde. Modi aut rerum iure exercitationem fugit similique tenetur maxime saepe, vitae laudantium minus ad repudiandae cumque ea dolorum eaque distinctio autem provident officiis facilis, atque veritatis reiciendis animi. Consequatur quam eveniet doloremque sequi inventore, explicabo excepturi beatae facilis porro quibusdam suscipit. Id fugit fugiat vel excepturi autem quae, recusandae provident ipsum, praesentium ex facilis aspernatur amet dolore dolorum? Dicta quod pariatur autem nulla explicabo corporis sunt necessitatibus ad natus rerum suscipit, velit sequi maiores quam? Culpa, quisquam odit.</div>
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`bootstrap` has solution to this. Simple add `mx-auto` to last div i will center div. Check my snippet.

FYI : bootstrap has in-build border with color https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/borders/#border-color

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-sm-start justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 border border-danger mx-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum dolores, veritatis tempore nihil explicabo mollitia doloribus laborum! Cupiditate, saepe. Commodi, mollitia? Sit quia magnam commodi inventore impedit quam nam voluptate est odio, alias
      unde a doloribus aliquid beatae eaque recusandae corrupti delectus reprehenderit ipsa dolorum hic. Labore possimus eos amet. Officia porro vel, veritatis minus natus tempore ratione quo nostrum, adipisci laboriosam temporibus qui. Architecto possimus
      laboriosam explicabo iusto! Minus iusto amet aperiam voluptatum libero placeat vero, molestias dolorem vitae eius doloremque optio? Ea blanditiis distinctio similique labore odio culpa, quis nobis veniam sapiente sed. Illum labore saepe doloremque
      sapiente.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 border border-danger mx-auto">Et laborum libero dignissimos ea molestias, quae rerum veritatis harum quidem soluta! Perferendis cumque minima modi enim ducimus exercitationem accusantium facilis dolore corrupti ab, esse autem. Illo inventore tenetur aut recusandae nostrum dolorum
      dolore doloribus nihil cupiditate. Voluptas ex commodi expedita atque sint obcaecati iure explicabo ipsam quo consequatur laudantium officia autem recusandae sapiente quae excepturi a culpa sunt, ratione quis tenetur vitae odio corrupti. Perspiciatis
      blanditiis, debitis eaque sequi porro hic minus ex adipisci iste ad accusamus aut atque eius mollitia error ducimus labore praesentium sed dolorem? Incidunt eaque ex eum unde ducimus et libero repudiandae aliquid porro nesciunt.</div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 border border-danger mx-auto">Laboriosam itaque labore iusto quidem ipsum quae et ipsam alias incidunt cumque, nobis quaerat corporis inventore! Quibusdam et ipsam quam pariatur unde. Modi aut rerum iure exercitationem fugit similique tenetur maxime saepe, vitae laudantium minus
      ad repudiandae cumque ea dolorum eaque distinctio autem provident officiis facilis, atque veritatis reiciendis animi. Consequatur quam eveniet doloremque sequi inventore, explicabo excepturi beatae facilis porro quibusdam suscipit. Id fugit fugiat
      vel excepturi autem quae, recusandae provident ipsum, praesentium ex facilis aspernatur amet dolore dolorum? Dicta quod pariatur autem nulla explicabo corporis sunt necessitatibus ad natus rerum suscipit, velit sequi maiores quam? Culpa, quisquam
      odit.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not like this, see my snippet if it is going sm device the right side looks like some margin and not center totally, I need the effect in sm device the column will full center but the last child not center so that I tried justify-content-start but if I use jutify-content-start the all column not center but I need all column center but last child not center the left side position first child and last child should be same

Comment: @NIKHILCHANDRAROY Reason is bootstrap `col-sm-5` both div has total of `10` and rest `2` is that space. Check snippet now

Comment: I need using col-sm-5 not col-sm-6 to center

Comment: @NIKHILCHANDRAROY still you can use `mx-auto` even if you use `col-sm-5` check my updated answer.

Comment: I think you don't understood me, if I use mx-auto, justify-content-center, ml-auto, mr-auto the last child not what I want, to left position first child and last child should me same

Comment: see http://prntscr.com/qrke36 I want like this using col-sm-5

Comment: @NIKHILCHANDRAROY i don't understand. how do you want ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
    .border{
       border:  1px solid red!important;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="p-0 m-0">

   <div class="container">
       <div class="row justify-content-md-center justify-content-start">
           <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3  border">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum dolores, veritatis tempore nihil explicabo mollitia doloribus laborum! Cupiditate, saepe. Commodi, mollitia? Sit quia magnam commodi inventore impedit quam nam voluptate est odio, alias unde a doloribus aliquid beatae eaque recusandae corrupti delectus reprehenderit ipsa dolorum hic. Labore possimus eos amet. Officia porro vel, veritatis minus natus tempore ratione quo nostrum, adipisci laboriosam temporibus qui. Architecto possimus laboriosam explicabo iusto! Minus iusto amet aperiam voluptatum libero placeat vero, molestias dolorem vitae eius doloremque optio? Ea blanditiis distinctio similique labore odio culpa, quis nobis veniam sapiente sed. Illum labore saepe doloremque sapiente.</div>
           <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3 border ">Et laborum libero dignissimos ea molestias, quae rerum veritatis harum quidem soluta! Perferendis cumque minima modi enim ducimus exercitationem accusantium facilis dolore corrupti ab, esse autem. Illo inventore tenetur aut recusandae nostrum dolorum dolore doloribus nihil cupiditate. Voluptas ex commodi expedita atque sint obcaecati iure explicabo ipsam quo consequatur laudantium officia autem recusandae sapiente quae excepturi a culpa sunt, ratione quis tenetur vitae odio corrupti. Perspiciatis blanditiis, debitis eaque sequi porro hic minus ex adipisci iste ad accusamus aut atque eius mollitia error ducimus labore praesentium sed dolorem? Incidunt eaque ex eum unde ducimus et libero repudiandae aliquid porro nesciunt.</div>
           <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-3  border">Laboriosam itaque labore iusto quidem ipsum quae et ipsam alias incidunt cumque, nobis quaerat corporis inventore! Quibusdam et ipsam quam pariatur unde. Modi aut rerum iure exercitationem fugit similique tenetur maxime saepe, vitae laudantium minus ad repudiandae cumque ea dolorum eaque distinctio autem provident officiis facilis, atque veritatis reiciendis animi. Consequatur quam eveniet doloremque sequi inventore, explicabo excepturi beatae facilis porro quibusdam suscipit. Id fugit fugiat vel excepturi autem quae, recusandae provident ipsum, praesentium ex facilis aspernatur amet dolore dolorum? Dicta quod pariatur autem nulla explicabo corporis sunt necessitatibus ad natus rerum suscipit, velit sequi maiores quam? Culpa, quisquam odit.</div>
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query to get the desired output. For the mobile device width, you want to center, add css effects using media query and make it center. Then it will apply only for the mobile device width you mention in the media query. You can use media query as follows
Add this to your css file or in between the  tag. Example is,

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
    /* styles to make the content center */
}
```

Like this add the relevant width of the mobile device you want. Hope this will help.